# how to filter a list in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops

I have a list that I want to filter.

```
[[100]][[1]]$total
[1] 7


[[100]][[2]]
[1] 7

[[100]][[3]]
[1] 25082.66
```

this is the output I get from my script, I am trying to filter all elements from this list where total = 7. I have a total of 100 elements.

my list is labelled as sorts

```
 A<-(list.filter(sorts,total>6))
```

I want to have a list with only elements where total is 7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can extract `"total"` element from each list and select only those elements with 7 in it.

```
lst[sapply(lst, "[[", "total") == 7]

#[[1]]
#[[1]]$total
#[1] 7

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[1]][[3]]
#[1] 2


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$total
#[1] 7

#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[2]][[3]]
#[1] 2
```

Or we can also use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) x[["total"]] == 7, lst)
```

---

Using `purrr` we can use `keep`/`discard`

```
library(purrr)
keep(lst, ~.[["total"]] == 7)

discard(lst, ~.[["total"]] != 7)
```

Or `map_lgl`

```
lst[map_lgl(lst, ~.[["total"]] == 7)]
```

**data**

Assuming your list is called `lst` and looks like the following

```
lst <- list(list(total = 100, 1, 2), list(total = 7, 2, 2), 
        list(total = 7, 2, 2), list(total = 71, 2, 2))
```

Answer (score 6):

We can use `pluck` and `map`

```
keep(lst, map(lst, pluck, "total") == 7)
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$total
#[1] 7

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[1]][[3]]
#[1] 2


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$total
#[1] 7

#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[2]][[3]]
#[1] 2
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(list(total = 100, 1, 2), list(total = 7, 2, 2), 
        list(total = 7, 2, 2), list(total = 71, 2, 2))
```